# Regular Expressions: count the number of numeric characters between two specific characters in a string in google sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In google spreadsheets, using regular expressions, how can I count the characters, numeric only, that are between the first hyphen of a string (from left to right) and the first comma after the hyphen?
The correct thing would be to count only the characters "2, 3, 4 and 5", that is, 4 characters.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the regex `"-.*?(\d*).*?,"` to get the number out with `REGEXTRACT(A2, "-.*?(\d*).*?,")` and then use `LEN` to get the length:

`=LEN(REGEXTRACT(A2, "-.*?(\d*).*?,"))`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "-.+?,"), "[0-9]+")
```

[image]